# PyCharm: Numbers to check Speed of PC

Tags: pycharm

Some people are shy and won't tell the admin if an application is slow.

Can I get some reliable numbers about the speed of the PC via PyCharm?

I don't want artificial benchmark values, but real-world values of the daily PyCharm usage.

Then you can check these numbers and see which developer PC needs a hardware upgrade.

Comment: Maybe these will help https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/profiler.html , https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360006387480--Large-1500-line-files-are-slow-with-inspections-CPU-heats-up and https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241235-Reporting-performance-problems

Answer (score 0):

A few things to consider:

- an application being "slow" is rather subjective, different people often use an application in different ways and with different settings
- different people perceive passing of time differently
- the same application used in exactly the same way may produce dramatically different timing figures depending on what else is running on the same machine
- the OS matters as well - I feel that I'm waiting for PyCharm on Windows on a more powerful recent desktop more often than on my 5+ years old laptop running Linux. Donno if relevant.
- being an IDE, most often PyCharm is waiting for user input, many operations are performed in the background

It may still be possible to come out with some sort of benchmark using PyCharm that can be used to decide on hardware upgrades. I would base it on the starting time given the number of open projects and the number of files open in each project. From my experience starting PyCharm represents the heaviest machine usage. Of course, to make it relevant the impact of the other variables should be minimised through the benchmark context/conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will be the best and most elegant way to achieve this but it's probably a fair solution.

My suggestion is to write a PyCharm plugin, that will use OS commands underneath to find out what you are looking for (CPU usage for example) and then send this periodically to admin over time along with the PC hostname/identifier.

I understand that this is not the easiest way to do it and will require some development, but if you are willing to spend time on it and if what you are looking for is possible to be implemented as a plugin for the IDE, you could potentially come up with a very powerful plugin for the needs of your company, in my opinion.

I don't have any experience with JetBrains plugins for any of their IDEs so I don't know anything technically about writing JetBrains plugins; it could be that what I suggest is not possible, but I thought to share this idea, should be useful to you.